# VB.NET Get the V variable from a youtube url

Tags: vb.net, url, youtube

I am writing a program to play videos from the internet in it.

for the user to get the video they have to paste a url in E.G. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xniR1GN69U that url works but this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=c4-overview&list=UUOYWgypDktXdb-HfZnSMK6A&v=5xniR1GN69U dosnt

this is my currunt code
[image]

how do i get it to just the v varibale from the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just request the parameter v?

```
Request("v")
```

or

```
Request.Querystring("v")
```

EDIT

If in winforms. You can apply as suggested by @Markus

Try it like this

```
    Dim querystring As String = url.Query

    Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim MyRegEx As New Regex("v=+(\w+)")
    myMatches = MyRegEx.Matches(querystring)

    For Each Row In myMatches
        AxShockFlashMovie1.Movie = "https://www.youtube.com/v/" & Row.ToString() & ""
    Next
```

You will also need to include

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Comment: is this for asp.net or will it work in a windows form

Comment: No, not yet. Im going to try later as i was working on UDP broadcasting in another program

Comment: I have just tested it it includes the v=

Comment: fixed the includeing v= problem now

Answer (score 2):

Your querystring looks like `"?v=5xniR1GN69U"` the first time and `"?feature=c4-overview&list=UUOYWgypDktXdb-HfZnSMK6A&v=5xniR1GN69U"` the second time. You could have figured that out by yourself by simply debugging and checking your variables, since it doesn't even reach the code in the if block... Making a screenshot doesn't help people to figure out what's wrong with your code.

You might want to use Regex to parse the id `Regex.Match(str, "v=(\w+)").Groups(1).Value`

Comment: i had to use a screen shot because the code didnt play well with stack extage code funtion

Answer (score 0):

I've used [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) in the past for something similar. Don't forget that youtube also offer tiny version of the urls with http://youtu.be/???